# PCI WiFi card on a raspberry pi

Tags: pi-2, pci

I want to know if it is possible and if it is how to connect a pci wifi card to my raspberry pi. Reason for this is simply the fact that i want to connect to a wifi signal and then use the pi as a server to share that wifi to a network

Comment: Look for USB WiFi adapters. Where exactly would you want to connect a PCI device?

Answer (score 1):

No , you cannot use PCI cards with any Raspberry Pi. No , you cannot "bitbang" PCI over the Raspberrys GPIO.